# Sorting on Column in Type Table with ColdFusion ORM

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have three tables, with the following structure:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2586403/ORMIssues/TableLayout.png

The three objects I'm dealing with are here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2586403/ORMIssues/Objects.zip

I need to be able to get a PartObject, and then pull all of its Attributes, sorted by the AttributeName in the Types table. Here are the problems I'm running into:

1. I can't sort the Attributes property in PartObject by its 
   Attribute.AttributeName property
2. I can't add the Attribute.AttributeName property to the ObjectAttribute entity because I get an error regarding column names. Hibernate is putting the ID on the wrong side of the join

Here's the hibernate log file showing the bad query

```
10/14 16:36:39 [jrpp-12] HIBERNATE DEBUG - select objectattr0_.ID as ID1116_, objectattr0_.AttributeValue as Attribut2_1116_, objectattr0_.AttributeID as Attribut3_1116_, objectattr0_1_.AttributeName as Attribut2_1117_ from ObjectAttributes objectattr0_ inner join Attributes objectattr0_1_ on objectattr0_.ID=objectattr0_1_.AttributeID 
10/14 16:36:39 [jrpp-12] HIBERNATE ERROR - [Macromedia] [SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'AttributeID'. 
10/14 16:36:39 [jrpp-12] HIBERNATE ERROR - [Macromedia] [SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Here's the offending section of the query:

```
from ObjectAttributes objectattr0_ 
inner join Attributes objectattr0_1_ on objectattr0_.ID=objectattr0_1_.AttributeID
```

It should be:

```
from ObjectAttributes objectattr0_ 
inner join Attributes objectattr0_1_ on objectattr0_.AttributeID=objectattr0_1_.ID
```

The AttributeName property on the ObjectAttribute.cfc is the one causing the problem:

```
component  output="false" persistent="true" table="ObjectAttributes" 
{ 
        property name="ID" column="ID" generator="native" type="numeric" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" unsavedvalue="0" ; 
        property name="AttributeValue" type="string" ; 
        property name="Attribute" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Attribute" fkcolumn="AttributeID" fetch="join"; 
        property name="AttributeName" table="Attributes" joincolumn="AttributeID" ; 
}
```

I've also tried using a formula to get the AttributeName on the ObjectAttribute entity, like so:

```
component  output="false" persistent="true" table="ObjectAttributes"
{
    property name="ID" column="ID" generator="native" type="numeric" ormtype="int" fieldtype="id" unsavedvalue="0" ;
    property name="AttributeValue" type="string" ;
    property name="Attribute" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Attribute" fkcolumn="AttributeID" fetch="join";
    property name="AttributeName" type="string" formula="(SELECT A.AttributeName FROM Attributes A WHERE A.ID = AttributeID)";
}
```

This works, but I can't sort by that computed column. If I then adjust PartObject.cfc like so:

```
property name="Attributes" cfc="ObjectAttribute" type="array" fkcolumn="ObjectID" fieldtype="one-to-many" orderby="AttributeName";
```

I get the following errors in the hibernatesql log:

```
10/17 16:51:55 [jrpp-0] HIBERNATE DEBUG - select attributes0_.ObjectID as ObjectID2_, attributes0_.ID as ID2_, attributes0_.ID as ID244_1_, attributes0_.AttributeValue as Attribut2_244_1_, attributes0_.AttributeID as Attribut3_244_1_, ((SELECT A.AttributeName FROM Attributes A WHERE A.ID = attributes0_.AttributeID)) as formula25_1_, attribute1_.ID as ID246_0_, attribute1_.AttributeName as Attribut2_246_0_ from ObjectAttributes attributes0_ left outer join Attributes attribute1_ on attributes0_.AttributeID=attribute1_.ID where attributes0_.ObjectID=? order by attributes0_.AttributeName
10/17 16:51:55 [jrpp-0] HIBERNATE ERROR - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'AttributeName'.
10/17 16:51:55 [jrpp-0] HIBERNATE ERROR - [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Here's a dump *without* that property to show that the rest of the relationships are working properly:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2586403/ORMIssues/Dump.pdf

I have no idea how to fix this issue. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Regarding 1), why can't you just use one of the sort methods from cflib.org to do it ? What code are you using to conclude "can't sort by that computed column" ?

Comment: I'm using `property name="Attributes" cfc="ObjectAttribute" type="array" fkcolumn="ObjectID" fieldtype="one-to-many" orderby="AttributeName";` to try and order by the computed column. That gives me the last error message listed above.

Comment: Have you/could you use ORMExecuteQuery and HQL to gain more control over the ORDER BY?

Comment: Sam's suggestion is the one you should shoot for - forcing this into the entity config is asking for more pain than necessary.

Comment: @Sam and @scrittler: I think that's the way I'm going to go based on a blog post I read by Nic Tunney. I just don't like it. It doesn't "feel right", as it seems from everything I've read that it should be technically possible. Oh well, what should be and what is don't always match up...

Comment: Sam's CF advice is nearly always correct.

Comment: Hey Sam, if you can enter your comment as an Answer I'll mark this question as answered. I ended up setting the Attributes property to just be a non-ORM-based array, and then in my Service I call setAttributes and use ORMExecuteQuery to get the objects in the order I want. Works great, though not technically ideal. We do what we can :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one with Sam's help, by setting up a method in my Service that returned the items in the order I wanted. I just used ORMExecuteQuery to get the items in the right order, and if there were no items, just returned an empty array.

The final method looked like this, where specifications are set directly in the object in the order I want them:

```
/**
@hint Gets a SpecGroups object based on ID. Pass 0 to retrieve a new empty SpecGroups object
@ID the numeric ID of the SpecGroups to return
@roles Admin, User
*/
remote ORM.SpecGroups function getSpecGroup(required numeric ID){
    if(Arguments.ID EQ 0){
        return New ORM.SpecGroups();
    }else{
        LOCAL.SpecGroup = EntityLoadByPK("SpecGroups", Arguments.ID);
        LOCAL.SpecsInGroup = ORMExecuteQuery("SELECT Spec FROM SpecInGroup G WHERE G.SpecGroupID = :GroupID ORDER BY SpecLabel, SpecName", {GroupID = LOCAL.SpecGroup.getID()});
        LOCAL.SpecGroup.setSpecifications(LOCAL.SpecsInGroup);
        return LOCAL.SpecGroup;
    }
}
```