# ColdFusion ORM: sort order for entity relationships

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I've got an app which contains a number of sports clubs, each having a number of contacts.

Each contact can be one of a number of types, and there's a specified display order for these.

I want to specify this sort order for the contacts in my entity relationship, but can't quite see how to do it.

To clarify things a little, here are my three (simplified) entity CFCs:

**club.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="clubs"
{
    // identifier
    property name="clubid" fieldtype="id" setter="false" generator="identity";

    // properties
    property name="clubname";

    // relationships
    property name="contacts" cfc="contact" singularname="contact" fieldtype="one-to-many" fkcolumn="clubid";
}
```

**contact.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="contacts"
{
    // identifier
    property name="contactid" fieldtype="id" setter="false" generator="identity";

    // properties
    property name="clubid";
    property name="name";

    //relationships
    property name="contacttype" cfc="contacttype" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="type";
}
```

**contacttype.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="contacttypes"
{
    // identifier
    property name="type" fieldtype="id" insert="false" update="false";

    // properties
    property name="typename";
    property name="displayorder";    
}
```

So, in summary, what I want to do is get the club with its contacts sorted according to the displayorder value in contacttype.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm wondering if you can use Sam Farmer's suggestion for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3945734/8174) ... it looks like that question is about a situation similar to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you need to override `getContacts` in club.cfc to do a custom lookup using HQL. Unfortunately I'm no HQL wizard, and I don't have your db to test this against. But here's my somewhat wild guess at the HQL:

```
public array getContacts()
{
    return ormExecuteQuery(
        "from club cl, contact co, contacttype ct
         where co.clubid = cl.clubid and cl = :thisClub
         order by ct.displayorder"
        , { thisClub = this }
    );
}
```

I'm sure that's not right, but hopefully it'll get you started.

Comment: I've just tried this (with a little bit of tweaking), and got it working, but the problem is that it fires off a query for every time it runs getContacts(), i.e. once for every contact. If I could do it via a property relationship and fetch="join", it would be much more efficient...