# How do I sort and filter an in-memory array of ORM objects in ColdFusion?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sorting, array-filter

Let's say I have a `Store` entity that contains a collection of `Products`. So I grab my `Store` and `Products` like this:

```
var store = entityLoadByPK("Store", 13);
var products = store.getProducts();
```

Now I'd like to sort and filter `Products`, which at this point is an in-memory collection (let's assume that the proxies have been resolved). Is this possible in ColdFusion, and if so, how would I do it?

**Side note**: I'm basically looking for something similar to C# LINQ's features, where I can do:

```
var store = session.Query<Store>().Single(x => x.Id == 13);
var products = store.GetProducts();
var sortedProducts = products.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
var filteredProducts = products.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Shampoo"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to use HQL to make that happen. I have a [question I posted some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945734/sorting-on-column-in-type-table-with-coldfusion-orm) that had to do with getting items back in a specific order. I ended up creating a custom `getProducts` method, instead of using the built in getter. That get method then ran the necessary HQL to return the records in the order required.

My question involves a join table in the middle, but the same concepts should apply.

```
public Products[] function getProducts(string SortColumn = "Name"){
    return EntityLoad("Products", {FKID = getID()}, Arguments.SortColumn & " ASC")
}
```

In the above case, FKID is the foreign key column in your products table, and getID is the default getter for the PK in your Store object.

I updated the answer to allow you to pass in the sort value as well :). Gotta keep it fancy...

Answer (score 2):

You may also specify the default comparative and sorting behavior of a relational collection by declaring the "where" and "orderBy" property attributes on the parent entity of a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. Below is an abbreviated example, followed by a reference to the supporting documentation.

**Parent.cfc**

```
component persistent="true"
{
     property cfc="Child" fieldType="one-to-many" name="Children" where="Age >= 18" orderBy="Name ASC, Age DESC"
}
```

**Child.cfc**

```
component persistent="true"
{
     property cfc="Parent" fieldType="many-to-one" name="Parent"
}
```

**Reference**

[Adobe ColdFusion 9 > ORM > Mapping > Define Relationship](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS5FFD2854-7F18-43ea-B383-161E007CE0D1.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like what you're hoping for... Boy do I wish there was!

Here's the best I can find for ya: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_sort_an_array_of_objects_or_entities_with_C-17958.html

Comment: But the OP is using ORM, so you can use built in ORM and Hibernate functions to sort the array before returning it. Straight arrays? Nope. ORM Arrays? Sure! :)

Comment: I think what I'll end up doing is creating a repository for my `Products` and access it using that. Not really a big fan of filling up my `Store` entity with a bunch of methods to filter on `Products`, even though a `Product` doesn't mean much without the `Store`.